# New twitter's API

Tags: twitter, twitter-anywhere

twitter today presented [new APIs](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin)

Please look at "User login & signup". So there is explained how to authenticate user. And according to this code it's simple to authenticate user at client-side. But how to get auth data now at server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter @Anywhere has short lived tokens that will not be useful for sever side API querying. You should look into the standard OAuth method of authenticating with Twitter.

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

Comment: so what is the usage area for new APIs then?

Comment: Easy integration into third-party web applications while the user currently interacting with the third-party website.